# Set default value to 1 for multiple variables at once in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculation

I am doing math calculations in javascript. I have to get values from input fields as they entered. Many of them can be blank. So in blank case, that value should be 1.

Here is my code-

```
var this_item = jQuery(this).parents('.row');
let item_quantity, item_length, item_width, item_height, item_weight = 1;
item_quantity = this_item.find('.item_quantity').val();
item_length = this_item.find('.item_length').val();
item_width = this_item.find('.item_width').val();
item_height = this_item.find('.item_height').val();
item_weight = this_item.find('.item_weight').val();
alert(item_weight);
```

Suppose 'item_weight' is empty, it should alert 1. But its showing me blank with above code.

Anyone can give me some idea?

Comment: Sorry can you explain your point? @RokoC.Buljan

Answer (score 2):

You could find all the elements, then use `map` to give a proper default value for each one.

```js
const [item_quantity, item_length, item_width, item_height, item_weight] =
     this_item.find('.item_quantity, .item_length, .item_width, .item_height, .item_weight')
              .map((_, el) => +(el.value || 1)).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is that you are initializing item_weight as 1 so then immediately it is overwriting its value with the value from the input field  even if it's blank. To get where you default to 1 if the input field is empty, you should check if the input is blank and only update item_weight if it's not. Here is the code:

```
var this_item = jQuery(this).parents('.row');
let item_quantity, item_length, item_width, item_height, item_weight;
item_quantity = this_item.find('.item_quantity').val();
item_length = this_item.find('.item_length').val();
item_width = this_item.find('.item_width').val();
item_height = this_item.find('.item_height').val();
item_weight = this_item.find('.item_weight').val();

// Check if item_weight is blank (empty or whitespace), then set it to 1
if (item_weight === '' || item_weight.trim() === '') {
  item_weight = 1;
}

alert(item_weight);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

In the case where you don't want *all* your values to default to "1" (eg if one of them is intended to input text), you can apply

```
.val() || "1"
```

eg:

```
var this_item = jQuery(this).parents('.row');
let item_quantity, item_length, item_width, item_height, item_weight = 1;
item_quantity = this_item.find('.item_quantity').val() || "1";
item_length = this_item.find('.item_length').val() || "1";
item_width = this_item.find('.item_width').val() || "1";
item_height = this_item.find('.item_height').val() || "1";
item_weight = this_item.find('.item_weight').val() || "1";
alert(item_weight);
```

Your choice if you use `"1"` or `1`.  As they appear to be numeric values, you probably want to convert them to numbers after.

---

As an aside, you might like to consider using a single variable here, eg:

```
var this_row = jQuery(this).parents('.row');

let item = { };
item.quantity = this_row.find('.item_quantity').val() || "1";
item.length = this_row.find('.item_length').val() || "1";
item.width = this_row.find('.item_width').val() || "1";
item.height = this_row.find('.item_height').val() || "1";
item.weight = this_row.find('.item_weight').val() || "1";

// output all fields with one statement
console.log(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let item_quantity = 1; // now item_quantity is 1
item_quantity = this_item.find('.item_quantity').val() // now item_quantity is ''
```

You can use conditional operator

```js
var this_item = jQuery(this).parents('.row');
let item_quantity;
item_quantity = this_item.find('.item_quantity').val();
item_quantity = item_quantity === '' ? 1 : item_quantity
```

Comment: Thanks but its lengthy for multiple variables

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
item_weight = this_item.find('.item_weight').val() ? this_item.find('.item_weight').val() : 1;
```